# How to access parent route props from child route

Tags: javascript, react-router

```
<Route path='/' parentProp='foo'>
  <IndexRoute component={IndexComponent} />
  <Route path='child' component={ChildComponent} childProp='bar'/>
</Route>
```

In my ChildComponent I have access to childProp via this.props.route.childProp. Now I would also like to have access to `parentProp` in some way without having to set it on the child route explicitly. Is this possible?

I would think it makes sense to pass props down to children the same way that all routeParams from the url are available in the children / leaf components.